# Is there a colloquial term for “dimensional reduction” in a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I’ve always used the term `fold` and `collapse`, but that’s always internally with colleagues. I’m wondering if there’s a more conventional term for this?

Specifically, I’m hoping to describe something like `fold Matrix into Series` and `collapse Matrix into Scalar value`

For example

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Folds to via summation along X-axis

```
12 15 18
```

And collapses to via summation...

`45`

Comment: This is different than what I think of when someone says "dimensional reduction".  I would think of something like Principle Component Analysis (PCA) or something similar.  Generally, I would refer to the reduction by whichever algorithm was used to achieve it.  I'm not sure what to call collapsing all of the numbers into a scalar.  When would this be used?

Comment: Hah yeah, I put “dimension reduction” in quotes specifically because I didn’t think I was referring to the academic sense of the word. In terms of use case, it’s useful in Simulations where you have entities vs ticks where the intersection is some form of contribution, and you want to find a sum of all value contributions (e.g. total cost)

Comment: In the language of the [Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html), the "fold" operation would be described as a "summation along the first dimension" i.e. a "summation along each column". This agrees with the language used in the [Numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html).

Comment: In the functional programming world, these are often called reductions or folds. But to explain to friends I would usually say "row-sums", "column-sums", or "sum of entries".